# Deserialize JSON to Custom Class - Object is null

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have an AJAX call that sends the following JSON to my webservice:

```
{"Tags":["12","5","2"],"TargetId":"36946","TargetType":"Officer"}
```

Here's the webservice and custom class:

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateTags(string PostParameters)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var tagData = serializer.Deserialize<TagData>(PostParameters);

    // do some stuff with tagData
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract(Name = "PostParameters")]
public class TagData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "TargetId")]
    string TargetId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "TargetType")]
    string TargetType { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Tags")]
    List<int> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, the properties of tagData are null. What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: Is that how your JSON arrives *exactly* or have you added in anything extra?

Comment: The JSON looks exactly like that when hovering over the PostParameters variable while in debug.

Comment: It's invalid JSON, run it through http://json2csharp.com and you'll see that it breaks. Also try services such as http://jsonlint.com and http://jshint.com

Comment: When hovering over PostParameters in debug ther should be a magnifier symbol. Click it and copy your JSON from there (and edit you question). That is exact value of string. What you posted has escaped double quotes.

Comment: I've updated the post per @Omilis instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties in TagData are not public. Make them public and it should work.

Also I would suggest using [JSON.NET](http://www.json.net). It is faster.

Comment: I've always thought that public was the default access modifier and this has worked in other classes, but marking these properties as public seemed to do the trick.